# How should I visit the U.K. after a voluntary departure?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, study, canadian-citizens, serial-refusals

I am a Canadian citizen. My family was on a Tier 1 Entrepreneur visa in the UK.

Our visa renewal was rejected multiple times, thus my sister and I opted for voluntary departure to return to Canada and reapply under tier 4 (student visas). Our departure was in September 2018. We are unable to do get student visas until September 2019 entry due to our universities’ policies, so will be applying in the summer and are currently taking a year out.

My sister has been granted a short-term student visa to return to the U.K. for one month to finish off her exams that she was unable to complete in June 2018 due to the visa refusal. She will be going in January 2019. I would also like to return to the U.K. to visit my family there. My parents, sister, husband, aunts/uncles and cousins are there. My husband and I are religiously married but not yet legally married due to visa issues - we are hoping to get the legal marriage done in Canada within the next few weeks.

My question is - what are my options for visiting the U.K.? Will I be refused entry on the assumption that I’m trying to live there, as my family is all there? My parents are currently there without a valid visa as they are still attempting to renew theirs. I’m hoping to stay in Ireland for the next 6 months so my family can visit me from the U.K. as Canada is too far. I should be granted a student visa to continue university in the U.K. starting in September. So because I’m in the middle of my university degree (3/5 years completed), and there’s no reason for me not to be granted a student visa in September 2019, can they still have issues with me visiting between now and then? Will they be suspicious of me staying in Ireland in the meantime? Should I get a work visa to stay in Ireland for 6 months to prove to U.K. immigration that I do intend to live there, or will a visit visa suffice? Should I ask my university to set up some research/placements so that I can get a short term student visa to visit? I am very desperate to visit my family there but do not want any issues with future immigration (obtaining my student visa for 2019).

Would appreciate all your help, thanks!

Comment: You are going to find it almost impossible to persuade UK immigration that you will observe the terms of a visitor visa with all your family ties and your studies in the UK, particularly since you appear to have overstayed in the past, and your family seem to be overstaying now. You have outlined several options here which together make the question too broad for this site. I'd suggest some expert advice from a UK immigration lawyer is in order.

Comment: @Anon This sounds like a complicated situation that needs advice from a qualified immigration lawyer.

Comment: So you’re guaranteed getting a visa in 2019 however you want to risk everything by trying to go back to visit this year? Is that a prudent decision?

Comment: @Anon What proof do you have that you are guaranteed a visa in 2019?

Comment: "there’s no reason for me not to be granted a student visa in September 2019," this is a very bold statement. From that, I think you should change you mind about what it is a visa. Nobody has the right to get a visa. Countries give them to some people, but it is nothing automated of granted. To you and your family: be careful with visa. A deportation could effect probabilities to get visa on many other countries.

Comment: We have gone through many immigration lawyers, very reputable ones from different different cities over the past few years, and no one has been helpful. It is a very complicated situation. Everyone was convinced that we would have an immigration ban for 12 months, yet my sister has been granted a visa. I am unable to trust any lawyers at the moment and believe the decision lies with the home office and immigration officials. Therefore I’m trying to find my best option for visiting, as I don’t believe visiting family in the U.K. is a crime.